# Does Bonjour networking work on ppc running 10.4?

Tags: iphone, wifi, bonjour, powerpc

I developed an application for Mac 10.5 desktop which communicates with iPhone over wifi using Bonjour service, and it is working fine on Mac 10.5 and able to do required syncing with iPhone over wifi using bonjour.

But same desktop app (although I recompiled for ppc 10.4 and there were some changes in coding like @property needed to be removed, etc.) doesn't work on ppc running 10.4.

I tried in both scenario:
1. Let Desktop be the server and iPhone will find service, published by desktop
2. Let iPhone be the server and desktop will find service, published by iPhone

but in both case I don't get success, either desktop not able to publish service or not able to find service.

Please let me know, if you also faced this type of bug and found some solution in this.
Also if you need more explanation, just ask me.

Thanks,
Sanniv

Answer (score 1):

Bonjour does work in 10.4, even PPC, so it seems like you have a Tiger-specific bug in your code.

Comment: I see 
Ok let me debug more to find where is the exact problem and why the callbacks are not being called. Hope I'll get it working :)